# Angular2 - get data before app loaded

Tags: angular

Im looking for a way to call a service on app load
if the service will fail I would need to show an error and not loading the app.

I saw about `APP_INITIALIZER` but it doesn't look like what I need
(on my AngularJs app I used `run` and displayed dialog on error)
Please help

Answer (score 0):

it depends of the service u want to implement. If for example ur service is a http call to a web api you can just put the message you want depending on the result :

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    // put ur message error here and redirect to onother route if u want
  });
```